# Doit-on écrire "Les lundis et vendredis soiR" ou "Les lundis et vendredis soirS" ? Et pourquoi?

Tags: accord, pluriel

Bonjour,
Comment accorder le mot "soir" dans le cas où il suit deux jours de la semaine? Selon moi, le mot "soir" doit être au singulier car on sous-entend "au soir" mais ma collègue a un doute. Selon elle, les "Lundis ET vendredis soir" font 2 soirs par semaine, donc il faudrait un "S" à "soir".
Existe-il une règle d'orthographe?
Merci !

Answer (score 3):

En fait, on peut écrire un peu n'importe quoi et c'est juste; par cela je veux dire que l'usage est très varié.

[image]

[les lundi et mardi soirs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20lundi%20et%20mardi%20soirs%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[les lundi et mardi soir](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20lundi%20et%20mardi%20soir%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[les lundis et mardis soirs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20lundis%20et%20mardis%20soirs%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
[les lundis et mardis soir](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20lundis%20et%20mardis%20soir%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Cependant, il existe des préférences qui sont plus ou moins matérialisées en ce que l'on pourrait appeler des règles.

> [La langue française](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/accord-jours-mois-les-lundis-les-janviers)  Il est erroné d'écrire « les jeudis soirs ». La bonne orthographe sera plutôt « les jeudis soir ».

Comme « les lundis et vendredis soir(s) » est une forme elliptique de  « les lundis soir et les vendredis soir », il existe a une solide indication que le plus logique est de ne pas utiliser d's pour « soir ».

Answer (score 3):

On a bien compris qu'il s'agit de « au soir », donc un emploi adverbial invariable peu importe le nombre d'éléments auxquels on l'applique mais on dit de l'emploi au pluriel qu'il est « [de plus en plus admis](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22685/la-grammaire/le-nom/nombre-des-noms-dans-certains-emplois/cas-particuliers-du-nombre-du-nom/pluriel-des-jours-de-la-semaine-et-des-divisions-de-la-journee) » (BDL). Le LBU discute de cette hésitation ou indécision vu que l'absence de la préposition semble changer la nature du mot et que l'idée de *soir* se superpose à celle du nom du jour dans un exemple comme « tous les lundis matin(s)/soir(s) » (LBU14 512 e). Traditionnellement, c'est invariable (BDL).